# How to get data from Parse.com database

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to use parse.com for my android application. I read the tutorial and I am able to insert the data but how do I retrieve it. I have attached the image of the my database

How to retrieve data of all the client Names from that database?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a ParseQuery to retrieve this data. Read Parse's Android Guide on using [Queries](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries).

Comment: ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.whereExists("ClientName");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> ClientList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + ClientList.size() + " scores");
        } else {
            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});

Comment: its giving me size correct but how do I get the value from the above query..If I am trying to print ClientList.toString() its giving me Parse Object values ... please help ..thanks

Comment: Can you add how you got the output to your question or else where here,it will be helpful..Thanks a lot..

Comment: I am facing the same problem , how did this guy approached the solution??

Answer (score 5):

You can get the values this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("UserMaster");
        query.whereEqualTo("userName",user_name);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> userList, ParseException e) {
                dlg.dismiss();
                 Log.d("klakla", "get: " + e+userList.size());
                 if (e == null) {
                     if (userList.size()>0) {

                     for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
                         ParseObject p = userList.get(i);                       
                      email = p.getString("email");
                      password  = p.getString("password");
                        } }

                    }
                 else {
                        Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                       // Alert.alertOneBtn(getActivity(),"Something went wrong!");
                    }   
            }
        });
```